# how to move to other line in <p> tag?

Tags: html, tags

I can't move from line to another in a `<p>` tag

I tried to click <kbd>enter</kbd> to move to another line like this:

```html
<p>
test

test
</p>
```

but it doesn't skip to a new line in the output

Comment: Use the `<br>` tag

Answer (score 1):

You can simple add a `<br>` inside `<p>` tag.
You can check at this snippet:

```html
<p>Message with no break</p>
<p>Message with <br> break</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Being `<p>` element doesn't mean you can put new lines with enter. You can do for example:

- add a `white-space: pre` style to a `<p>` element so the new lines are preserved (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_text_white-space)
- manually add `<br>` tag at the point you want to break text
- close previous and add new `<p>` tag